# Easy way to let OkHTTP logging interceptor to log only requests?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using normal logging of OkHTTP HTTP Request to Android logcat. However, if I configure the level to print BODY I get huge loads of responses which cause logcat buffer overflow and sometimes crash. Thus to workaround it I would like to log only requests.

Is there an almost out-of-the-box way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, it does not seem like that is an option. You might consider filing a feature request for this, if there is none already. Or, fork the repo and contribute the change. Or, copy the source and modify it to suit — it is less than 1000 lines of Kotlin, based on current `main`.